# Failed to compile the generated JSP java files

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, cannot-find-symbol

I'm using Neatbeans to deploy a simple project to GAE, I managed to deploy the "empty" project but now that I added a class I'm getting an error.

When I run: `appcfg update C:\Users\lsarni\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestMemcache\web`

I get the following error:

```
8% Compiling jsp files.
sep 15, 2016 3:16:16 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \index.jsp
C:\Users\lsarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1473963375861-0\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:6: error: package Memcache does not exist
import Memcache.GoogleMemcache;
               ^
C:\Users\lsarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1473963375861-0\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:6: error: package Memcache does not exist
import Memcache.GoogleMemcache;
               ^
C:\Users\lsarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1473963375861-0\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        GoogleMemcache x = new GoogleMemcache();
        ^
  symbol:   class GoogleMemcache
  location: class index_jsp
C:\Users\lsarni\AppData\Local\Temp\1473963375861-0\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
        GoogleMemcache x = new GoogleMemcache();
                               ^
  symbol:   class GoogleMemcache
  location: class index_jsp
3 errors

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
Unable to update app: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
```

The log says:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:1048)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1001)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:776)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:708)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:570)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1490)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:357)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:218)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:119)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:115)
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1490)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:357)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:218)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:119)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:115)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:1048)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:1001)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.populateStagingDirectory(Application.java:776)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:708)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:570)
    ... 6 more
```

This is the structure of my project, I'm not sure if placing the class GoogleMemcache there is the right thing to do.

[image]

Clean and build from Netbeans work just fine.

This is the code in `index.jsp`:

```
<%@page import ="Memcache.GoogleMemcache" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        GoogleMemcache x = new GoogleMemcache();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried the different answers I found to similar questions without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was trying to deploy the wrong folder:

```
appcfg update C:\Users\lsarni\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestMemcache\web
```

Should have been:

```
appcfg update C:\Users\lsarni\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestMemcache\build\web
```

I realized that was the wrong one because it was missing a `META-INF` folder so it didn't match the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20762784/3695939)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using scriplet tag for declaration of Object x

```
<%  GoogleMemcache x = new GoogleMemcache(); %>
```

use declarative tag

```
<%!  GoogleMemcache x = new GoogleMemcache(); %>
```